# c# cancel application from closing if hidden form has unsaved changes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, formclosing

after searching google and stackoverflow I'm unable to find an answer that helped me in my situation. I've got an application with a start menu(form). when the user presses the X(close) of a (any) form I reload the start menu. Now when that(menu) form gets closed I want to check and notify the user wheter any now hidden forms are in editing mode (with or without unsaved changes) if user presses cancel I want to show that form and stop the application from closing. Now my problem is how do i stop the application from stopping in the code of the other forms. I have an override of the dispose method of the subforms that calls this.close so the ok/cancel messagebox shows but after the MB the start menu closes anyway stopping the program. Should I look for a different method of handling these things or is there a method or eventhandler to modify so this /\ can work?

EDIT:
ok here's parts of the code in order of being called. Where does i go wrong?

```
private void Menu_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
       Global.Forms.Remove(this);
        if (!Global.Clean_Forms())
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            Global.Forms.Add(this);
        }
    }

public static void Clean_Forms()
    {


        foreach (Form f in Forms)
            {
                if (f is Menu)
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!f.IsDisposed)
                    {


                        f.Close();
                    }

                }

            }
        if (Forms.Count != 0)
        {
            isClean = false;
           /* String a = "";
            foreach (Form f in Forms)
            {
                a += f.ToString() + ": ";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(a);*/
        }
        else
        {
            isClean = true;
        }

    }
```

Yet this doesnt work, application just closes down.

the closing event handler of random form

```
private void persoon_form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (editing)
        {
            DialogResult dr;
            dr = MessageBox.Show("uw wijzigingen gaan verloren. Doorgaan?", "sluiten", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;


            }
            else if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Global.size = this.Size;
                Global.position = this.Location;
                Global.Forms.Remove(this);
                Form f = Global.menu();
                f.Show();
                this.Dispose();
            }
        }//somethingelse}
```

EDIT: @cody gray changed onclose and clean_form still no effect, (shouldn't the messagebox in the Closing event of the subform be shown anyway? cause it doesnt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figured it out! I changed two things. 1 I made sure that I didn't call this.dispose anywhere as that will result in disposing (not closing) any child forms hence no onclosing event is called. 2. the foreach loop when checking if main menu can close generated collection was modified errors. so with this I made sure it closes in the right order thnx Cody Gray for pointing me in the right direction:

```
Stack<Form> stack = new Stack<Form>();
            foreach (Form f in Forms)
            {
                if (f is Menu)
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!f.IsDisposed)
                    {


                        stack.Push(f);
                    }

                }

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < stack.Count; i++)
            {
                Form temp = stack.Pop();
                temp.Close();
            }
```

Comment: You're welcome. I couldn't help but notice the two things you "fixed" were things I had no way of knowing were wrong in the first place. You didn't tell me that you were calling the `Dispose` method on form objects from other places in your code (there's no reason to ever do that; use the `Close` method instead). You also didn't mention you were modifying the forms collection inside of a `foreach` loop (also a bad idea; use a backwards `for` loop or a separate `List<T>` if you need to do that). I'm glad to hear that you figured out an acceptable solution, though.

Answer (score 8):

You should not be doing this in the `Dispose` method. Instead, try handling the [**`FormClosing` event**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx).

This event occurs *before* the form is closed, so you can check whatever state you need to, and cancel the close if necessary by setting `e.Cancel` to True.

For example:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);

    // Check to see if the user is allowed to close this form
    if (!allowClose)
    {
       // Prevent this form from being closed
       MessageBox.Show("This form cannot be closed yet!");
       e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah I had already tried that, but that event doesnt get fired for some reason. I googled that and the solution I came up with was call this.close in the dispose event so I can do the e.cancel thing. the problem is. although e.cancel is true (that form doesnt close) but the 1st form (Application.Run(new Menu());) is still closing. And when that closes all forms get disposed anyway

Comment: @Daanvl: By the time that the `Dispose` method gets called (and thus, any code you've placed inside of it), it's way too late to cancel the form closing. I don't know where you found that solution suggested online, but that's never going to work the way you've explained it. You need to figure out a way to prevent the *main* form from closing. Override its `OnFormClosing` method to do so.

Comment: Forms is a custom form list (add, remove. just to keep track of opened forms)(Global is singleton type class). But main problem remains, If I cant use the dispose event, how can I assure that the onformclosing event gets fired? at the line f.close(); the form gets destroyed but no onclosing event code gets executed

Comment: @Daanvl: I suspect that the `FormClosing` event still gets raised. The problem is that no matter what value is returned, *all* of the forms are still getting closed because your *main* form is closed, regardless of whether individual forms cancel their close events. You need to prevent the main form from closing if there are still child forms open. Do that by overriding its `OnFormClosing` method and checking the `Forms` collection to make sure it's empty before you allow the close to occur.